# Why won’t first record picture update like all other records?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

With help from the community I now have a great input form that needs some tweaking:
Note the sample of six records:

[image]

[image]

If I advance (next record button) or back up (previous record button) through the records one at a time, or go to first record (using First Record button) they all display properly.

However, if I select any member from the Lookup Member combo, all the pictures display properly except the first record which always displays the last image.

Here is the code:

```html
Private Sub Form_Current()


Dim strPath As String

    If IsNull(Me!MemPicturePath) Then

    strPath = "C:\MEMBER DATA BASE\IMG.jpg"
    
    Me!MemPicturePath = strPath
    
    Me.Refresh
    
    MemberImage.Picture = Me.MemPicturePath

    End If


Me.MemberImage.Picture = Me!MemPicturePath
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Code behind the ComboBox?

Answer (score 0):

Solved....added Me.Refresh as the last line.